# Button onclick make other script stop running

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having below code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#buttonID").click( function() {
        // stop funcName() running
    });
});

$(function funcName(){
    // some scripts will run on page load
});
```

My question is how can i stop funcName() running when click at #buttonID.

Thank you guys.

EDIT: This is the script that will run on page load: https://jsfiddle.net/1t8z3Ls2/1/ (i found this script on Google. this script will make a div child become sticky to it's parent div.)

I want to make this script stop runnig by clicking on a button.

Thanks again.

Comment: depends on what it is....

Comment: What do you mean by "stop funcName() running"? If it's running on page load, it'll start before the button can be clicked. Is the script doing all synchronous things, or are there async things? If it's all synchronous, then no code can run in the middle of funcName(), so it will always complete. If there's async stuff, you can set a variable on the button click and then check that variable in your async handler callbacks to decide whether to ignore it or not.

Comment: Please provide more details, what you want to achieve and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @nircraft   Thank you, sir. I just added the script that i want to make it stop by clicking on a button. Can you guys please take a look.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Thanks, i just edited my post. Can you please take a look.

Comment: I see nothing in that script that is async, though it's quite hard to tell what you want to "stop" happening when you gave us a massive script that does many things. Do you want to stop the sticky elements from being sticky? Then you need to remove the window's scroll event handler that script sets. Although if you just want sticky elements, it'd be much easier to use the CSS `position: sticky` property instead of a script that you don't actually understand.

Comment: i am stucking in a problem. i am having a absolute button. if i make it sticky. it will break layout. so i think i will let it is absolute, and use a script to make it become sticky on scroll. 

i have two div in a <div display:flex justify-content-center>. i want to make first div is centered, second div closer to right margin. To make second one closer to right margin i let it absolute. And i need second one will be sticky inide parent div so i use a script.

Comment: the best way that i can think is i let second div sticky. and change it position, make it closer to the right margin. but i can't move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code:
- You have one red div 
- You have one button 
- In the CSS you have one animation declared but not used 
- When page is loaded, the first JS block code will be automatically executed, this block of code will assign animation 'moveRight' to div 'player' 
- The animation will make the player div move to the right for one second 
- If user click on the button 'Stop Animation', the function stopMoving() will be executed to stop the player div from moving 
Good luck!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    #player {
      min-width: 80px;
      min-height: 80px;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      left: 0%;
    }
    
    @keyframes moveRight {
      0% {
        top: 10%;
        left: 0%;
      }
      20% {
        top: 10%;
        left: 20%;
      }
      40% {
        top: 10%;
        left: 40%;
      }
      60% {
        top: 10%;
        left: 60%;
      }
      80% {
        top: 10%;
        left: 80%;
      }
      100% {
        top: 10%;
        left: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <button onclick="stopMoving()">Stop Animation</button>
  <div id="player"></div>

  <script>
    //This code will be executed on page load.
    //It will give the div 'player' an animation to make it move to the right
    let player = document.getElementById("player");
    player.style.animationName = "moveRight";
    player.style.animationDuration = "60s";
    player.style.animationFillMode = "forwards";



    function stopMoving() {
      //This function will be executed when user click on the button.
      //This function will stop the div from moving to the right                
      player.style.animationName = "";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is normally single threaded - meaning that while a function is executed in the browser no other code can run at the same time - including event handlers such as onclick (they will be triggered only after the function is complete). So, in this case you cannot interrupt the execution of a function from code.

There are two workounds:

The long running function could take breaks intentionally, allowing other code to execute.

```
//set this to true from an event handler to stop the execution
var cancelled = false;

function longRunningFunction() {
  if (cancelled) {
    return;
  } 

  // do some work, but not all
  // save your progress to be able to resume when called again

  if (!done) {
    // release control, so that handlers can be called, and continue in 10ms
    setTimeout(longRunningFunction, 10);
  }
}
```

Use [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage). They allow running code in parallel, but have some restrictions and are not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I am not really good at JS. But i just added the script that i want to make it stop running. Could you please take a look and please give me a specify solution for my case. Once again, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Events are executed right after the execution stack is empty. so you can't expect to be able to terminate a function that is already in execution stack by a click event. what you can do is to forth your funcName() to be executed in event loop. for example you can invoke your function as a callback function for requestAnimationFrame:

```
 docClick = document.getElementById("buttonID").addEventListener("click",function(){
 state=false;   
});

document.body.onload= function(){
    state = true;
    animationGame = requestAnimationFrame(Myfunc);
    function Myfunc(){
        if (state){
        console.log("hi");
        animationGame = requestAnimationFrame(Myfunc);  
        }   
    }
}
```